# Check if a RTMP-Stream is running and start ffmpeg to transcode the stream

Tags: scripting, ffmpeg, rtmp, stream

I'm using ffmpeg to transcode a rtmp-stream and re-stream it with ffmpeg.

I have 2 problems:

- how can I check if the remote rtmp-stream is running and then start ffmpeg
- sometimes ffmpeg breaks up transcoding and it must be restarted automatically

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I used "GOD" to solve my problem:

http://god.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've used mplayer with dumpstream + a filesizecheck for mms. (let it run for a few seconds, kill it, check if the file is large enough)
Maybe this will work for rtmp as well, but I don't know how reliable mplayer's support is.

Btw, title has the abbreviation wrong